# How to defeat IE10 weird "feature" that if table height set for 50% it calculates based on window height?

Tags: html, html-table

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html style = "height: 100%;">
    <head>
        <title>test height</title>
    </head>

    <body style = "height: 100%; margin: 0px;">
        <table border = '1' width = '100%' height = '100%'>
            <tbody height = '100%'>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan = '2' height = '1px'>asd</td>
                </tr>
                <tr height = '100%'>
                    <td width = '40%' height = '100%' align = 'center' valign = 'middle'>
                        <table border = '1' width = '90%' height = '50%'>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr><td>this should be 50% in height</td></tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td>qwe</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan = '2'>rty</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my code.
this is my calculations
[image]

The second table has 50% height of window height, instead of cell where it sits.
I don't know already how to defeat it. I placed `height = '100%'` to every possible parent already.

Comment: If you set the height of the row in which the cell is, not using Percentages, but using pixels, you will realize that it is, in fact, 50% the height of the cell, which is 100% to the height of the row. You did not take the borders into account. the borders can make your calculations in pixels to look wrong, although it is right. Just remember that something (usually the very outer part of the elements) has to have a definite height/width for your percentages to work correctly.

Comment: I think you wrong. if i set this table's height to 100%, it will fill whole window height, instead of filling parent td only.

Comment: Check out my answer i'm about to post. it will give you a good layout of what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the percentages - which I see all over the place. I don't see any fixed height for a parent element. For percentages, we need to have some height of some kind somewhere, excluding the window-height (try to be responsive in your designs). What does 100% Height on the BODY mean? It means that is fills the height of the visible part of the window.

This, essentially means that, whatever the height of the window, our elements will have that height. We don't know the height of the window. But we can put 100%, that is very easy.

In responsive design, the height of the parents are basically on auto. It should auto size the height. The content withing it determines the actual height. This way when you add more to your element, it auto sizes the height, automatically. - but still, we need some height somewhere to make our website look good.

Take this HTML I give you, and paste it in a clean html file. Now run this in whichever browser you choose - looks like it is IE.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Example</title>
        </head>
        <body style="height:500px; margin:auto;"> <!-- You set the body's height to 100%, so this will determine our dimentions. I use Pixels to make my point.-->
            <!-- GRAY -->
            <table style="width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid black; background:gray;">
                Main Table. [Height: 500px]
                <!-- GREEN -->
                <tr style="height:60px; background:green;">
                    <td colspan='2'>
                        Row 1, Cell 1 [Height: 60px]
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- RED -->
                <tr style="background:red;">
                    <td style="width: 40%;" align = 'center' valign = 'middle'>
                        Row 2, Cell 1 (Problem Cell) [Height: fills the rest of the space] [Width: 40% of containing cell.]
                        <!-- ORANGE -->
                        <table style="width: 50%; height: 50%; background: orange;">
                            <td>
                                Table that is 50% in height of it's containing cell, and also 50% the width of the containing cell.
                            </td>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Row 2, Cell 2 [Height: fills the rest of the space] [Width: fills rest of space.]
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- GREEN -->
                <tr style="height:90px; background:green;">
                    <td colspan='2'>
                        Row 3, Cell 1 [Height: 90px]
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>

Now play with the height on the body. Put percentages, and put pixels. Watch the behaviour.

That is why I say that your element is really the correct height. The borders are those that screw with your mind.

But the real advice is to have some height somewhere.
Rather use CSS @media and change your styles (heights) according to different screen sizes.

A example using @media:

        @media screen and (max-width: 599px)
        {
            body {
                height: 200px;
            }
        }
```

EDIT:
So I assume that this is what you really want: looking like your template:

```
<html style="height:100%;">
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body style="height:100%; margin:auto;"> <!-- You set the body's height to 100%, so this will determine our dimentions. I use Pixels to make my point.-->
        <!-- GRAY -->
        <table style="width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid black; background:gray;">
            Main Table. [Height: 500px]
            <!-- GREEN -->
            <tr style="height:60px; background:green;">
                <td colspan='2'>
                    Row 1, Cell 1 [Height: 60px]
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- RED -->
            <tr style="background:red;">
                <td style="width: 40%;" align = 'center' valign = 'middle'>
                    Row 2, Cell 1 (Problem Cell) [Height: fills the rest of the space] [Width: 40% of containing cell.]
                    <!-- ORANGE -->
                    <table style="width: 50%; height: 50%; background: orange;">
                        <td>
                            Table that is 50% in height of it's containing cell, and also 50% the width of the containing cell.
                        </td>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Row 2, Cell 2 [Height: fills the rest of the space] [Width: fills rest of space.]
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- GREEN -->
            <tr style="height:90px; background:green;">
                <td colspan='2'>
                    Row 3, Cell 1 [Height: 90px]
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is true, but what to do if I really need to have all heights at 100%? this work fine in IE11 and work fine in IE10 too, if I remove `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but this will break other things.

Comment: Then just put the body's height to 100%, which will fill the window. Whatever the size of the screen, that will be applied. Change the body's height to 100%. Then resize the window. This is still applied correctly. There is no problem with your code except that you try to style the html tag etc. But your code works. There is no problem. The borders makes your calculations look wrong. But your inner table in the cell, is actually correct. I'm just trying to show you the behavior. The borders makes the content look bigger, but just measure the elements, excluding their border's size.

Comment: @Kosmos - Please note that you then need to style the html tag to have a height of 100% as well - which you did in your original answer.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I decided to use onresize event and set body fixed height that is same as window height.

Comment: Even if nothing I said here helped, as long as something helped you to achieve what you want :).

Comment: No, the fact that some parent must have height set in pixels helped me. Thank you.